# container with volatile POD type

Tags: c++, volatile, dynamically-generated, allocator

I have some (say, dynamically generated) code and STL container with POD data (say, `std::vector< T >` of `static_assert(std::is_floating_point< T >::value, "!");`) which accessed from that code.

Apparently I need to declare the data with the `volatile` qualifier. But in such case **gcc** emits an errors:

```
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h:110: ошибка: invalid conversion from 'volatile void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
       { ::operator delete(__p); }

c:\mingw\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_construct.h:75: ошибка: invalid static_cast from type 'volatile double*' to type 'void*'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }

c:\mingw\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:372: error: invalid conversion from 'volatile void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
      __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
                                                         ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:372: error: invalid conversion from 'const volatile void*' to 'const void*' [-fpermissive]
```

Is this the only solution, that I should provide my own allocator with proper correction of pointer conversions?

Comment: _'Apparently I need to declare the data with the volatile qualifier.'_ Just for curiosity: Can you point out a reasonable use case for such construct?

Comment: @g-makulik `std::vector< volatile double >.data()` passed to dynamically generated code as value of base register to access `std::vector`'s elements. OK?

Comment: @g-makulik Or even all the elements of `std::vector< volatile T >` R/W accessed from plenty of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector of `volatile` objects cannot work with the standard allocator. There is a [GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57403) open on this, and it looks like a defect in the standard, not in GCC.

You have to provide your own allocator.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to cast from volatile T * to T* you need to use const_cast (surprise, surprise!). Further cast to void * will require static_cast or reinterpret_cast.

Comment: I.e. `static_cast< void * >(const_cast< typename rebind< std::remove_volatile< value_type > >::pointer >(_p))` ?

Comment: @KDukales: Well, don't know rebind... But something along the lines.

Comment: `template< typename U > struct rebind { using other = xallocator< U >; };` is mandatory for STL containers part of some allocator `xallocator` implementation, as I know.